# Get title from html page - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-html

I would like to create a preview of a url with the title and thumbnail in flutter

I downloaded the web page correctly with the http package, but I can't get the  tag
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

```
var document = parse('''<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
        <p>PAGE HTML!</p>
        <img src="image.jpg">
    </body>
  </html>''');


print("PRINT - "+document.body.getElementsByTagName('h1').toString()); --> ("PRINT - [<html h1>]") *
```

*I would like to get the h1 title : HELLO WORLD!

Thank you.

Comment: you should use Youtube API. In response of this api you can get all video related information

Comment: If I had a generic link not necessarily on youtube ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flutter-link-preview](https://github.com/devdennysegura/flutter-link-preview) plugin:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:link_preview/widget/whatsapp/index.dart';

WhatsAppLinkPreview whatsapp = WhatsAppLinkPreview();

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: whatsapp.build('https://whatsapp.com')
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: I wanted to implement it myself, but I can always change the class, thanks

Answer (score 0):

i did it once using
[html plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/html)
it gives you something like

```
var document = parse(response.body);
document.getElementById // or tagName or className
```

but you will get weird html element needs to be parsed

Comment: I can't get the text inside the <head> tag, could you show me some code to do it? thank you

Comment: if you just need to handle body elements, you could consider this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html)

Comment: I should get the string from the html page and then use it in my app

Answer (score -2):

```
print(document.body.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerHtml);
```

works most of the time.